# XML Sitemap submitted but few page show indexed via Google site: search

Tags: seo, google, sitemap

I submitted a sitemap of my website to Google. ([japan1900.com](https://japan1900.com/))
The sitemap : (https://japan1900.com/en/module/lgsitemaps/sitemap?fc=module&name=product_1_1)
The robots.txt : https://japan1900.com/robots.txt

Sitemap seems correct, Google validated 112 links in Google Search Console after only few hours.
However, if i look for my website with the following Google request : "site:japan1900.com" i see only 9 results. At this point i think it is not a question of time.

I should tell you that first time i sent the sitemap was 2 months ago and i deleted it 3 days ago and tried again. URL were validated twice but somehow never been reflected in search.

Also that i have a different website using the same architecture / sitemap and not having this issue.

What can i do to find the issue ? To me, sending the sitemap, receiving validation, would be enough to appears in Google Search, even with pretty bad ranking but appearing in "site:" search. Here something looks wrong, and i feel blocked.

Comment: Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox

Comment: XML sitemaps don't help with SEO very much.  They get your pages crawled, but Google makes decisions about which ones to index based on other factors such as uniqueness of contents and how many links they have.     Rather than build sitemaps, focus on improving your site so that users link to it.

Comment: thanks for both replies. Interesting !